# How to return the time() value in Select SQL report query

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

I am wanting to retrieve the UNIX `time()` value of an order placed from within my store cart.

**How do I get the Unix time from the time of order?**

I have used the following queries however they are both returning incorrect information.

1) returns the word `time()` in the report, not the actual digital value.

```
DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased, 'time()') As ref,  
returns:  time()
```

2)  When I use the next option I get the current time, NOT the time of purchase.

```
DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) As ref,
returns:  1421451235        17/01/2015 11:03
```

**Note:**
I have checked against the following:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

**Update**
My query is based on this:

```
Select  

DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased, '%Y-%m-%d') As ODate,  (works)  
(new line for Unix timestamp) eg: DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) As ref,

From /*PREFIX*/products T1  
Inner Join /*PREFIX*/orders T5 On (T5.orders_id = T2.orders_id)
```

The `'ref'` value was sent to the payment processing page from my cart, so it should be retrieved by SQL somehow.  `zen_draw_hidden_field('ref', time()) .`

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT` takes a date value as first, and a format as second parameter. So if `T5.date_purchased` contains a Unix timestamp, you can not feed it to `DATE_FORMAT` directly, you would have to convert it to a _date_ value first. There is however also a function `FROM_UNIXTIME`, that takes a Unix timestamp directly as first parameter (and a format as second).

Comment: @CBroe thank you, but how would I write that in the query?  I've update my question with my basic `SELECT` query for time / date info

Comment: That's very unhelpful given I've looked at the date & time functions and the function that I believe is the most useful returns the result of the word `time()`.  The one that does work gives me the current time value. Which I explained above.

Comment: have a look at `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function

Comment: @JanLegner I have, it returns the current timestamp, not the time of the order.  See #2 above.  2) When I use the next option I get the current time, NOT the time of purchase. 
`DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) As ref,
returns:  1421451235        17/01/2015 11:03  `

Comment: That is pretty obvious... But `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(T5.date_purchased)` should return timestamp of date purchased.

Comment: @JanLegner Thank you, that worked.  The issue is now the timezone is out. Server time is different from software time by 8.5 hours, so my UNIX time is showing 8.5hrs later than what the order actually was.  Order time:  `1413682753 = 19/10/2014 01:39:13`  UNIX time:  `1413707953 = 19/10/2014 19:09:13`.  Is there a way to offset the time?

Comment: Got it :)  `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(T5.date_purchased - interval 7 hour) as RefIDOffset,`  I had the answer there, I didn't know I could subtract hours.  Excellent

Comment: @JanLegner Just checking back. If you would like to make your answer, your 'the answer' I can then vote it up.  Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @MrsAdmin Glad I could have helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an answer from my comment as asked:

Solution is to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, which will return timestamp from the date/time value. So `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(T5.date_purchased)` should return  timestamp of date purchased. To subtract hours use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(T5.date_purchased - interval 7 hour)`

For further examples and usage see [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)